# Rails - How to access a Request Parameter from view in a helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do you access a view's request parameter inside a Helper?

My view `events/index7` sets the parameter date_selected:

```
<div><%= link_to 'View' , events_index7_path(:date_selected => date), :class => 'btn  btn-mini'%></div>
```

My helper is `app/helpers/calendar_helper.rb`

Here's a pic of it at the point in the Helper I where I want to access it.

[image]

I tried this:

```
classes << "dayselect" if day == DateTime.strptime(params[:date_selected], "%Y-%m-%d")
```

I get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `params' for #<CalendarHelper::Calendar:0x007f8d215671f0>
```

OR should I be passing the date to the helper in a different way?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 10):

`params` is a controller method, belongs to `ActionController:Metal` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Metal.html#method-i-params

It's possible to let View to touch `params` by exposing this controller method as a helper.

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :params
```

Then, in your view you can call this helper with `params` as argument. `my_helper(params)`

**But, wait, this breaks MVC principle**. View should not touch params at all. All these works should be done at controller level. What if the params is incorrect? You need controller to respond that, instead of passing that responsibility to view.

So, if you need to touch it in view, it's a smell. Review the whole process, there must be a better arrangement.

Comment: Can I pass the data some other way instead of a param?

Comment: I don't know your logic so the solution in answer is still like a hack. If I do that I will not let view to touch params which is not his business. Instead I'll prepare all thing in controller or model.